# Проблема с выводом информации из бд

Tags: python, django

Такая проблема: есть раздел с жилыми комлексами, у каждого жк есть отдельная страничка, на которой находятся карточки с домами. Хочу, чтобы при нажатии на карточку дома, выводилась информация этого дома из бд. Но при выборе любого дома выводится одна и та же информация (самого первого дома). Как это исправить?

Понимаю, что проверка {% if ap.house == house %} в шаблоне очень глупая( и предполагаю, что исправлять нужно вьюху

[image: Карточки с домами]

**Шаблон**

```
  <div class="house-section">
    <h2 class="text-left">Дома</h2>
    <div class="h-cards-wrapper">
      {% for house in houses %}

      <div class="h-card">
        <div class="h-card-info">
          <p class="house-title">Дом {{ house.house_number }}</p>
             <button class="btn btn-primary read-more h-btn" id="showCard" onClick="viewHouseCard()" >
              Подробнее
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="house-card" id="house-card">
        <button class="closeCard" onClick="closeHouseCard()">
          <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </button>

        <div class="card-content">
          <h1 class="white h-card-title">Дом {{ house.house_number }}</h1>
          <table class="table-container">

            <tr>
              <th>Номер <br> квартиры</th>
              <th>Этаж</th>
              <th>Кол-во <br> комнат</th>
              <th>Площадь</th>
              <th>Отделка</th>
              <th>Цена <br> за м2</th>
              <th>Цена за <br> объект</th>
              <th>Планировка</th>
            </tr>
            {% for ap in apartments %}
            {% if ap.house == house %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ap.apartment_number}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.level}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.room}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.square}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.finishing}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.price_m}}</td>
              <td>{{ap.price_total}}</td>
              <td><button class="view-plan" onClick="viewHousePlan()"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
             </tr>
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>

    {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
```

**views.py**

```
class ComplexDetailView(DetailView):
    active = ['service']
    model = Complex
    template_name = 'service/complex.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['gallery'] = ComplexGallery.objects.filter(complex=context['complex'])
        context['houses'] = House.objects.filter(complex=context['complex'])
        context['apartments'] = Apartment.objects.all()
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from .utils import *


class Complex(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='complex/', blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = from_cyrillic_to_eng(str(self.name))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.name


class ComplexGallery(models.Model):
    complex = models.ForeignKey(Complex, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    gal_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='complex/gallery/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.complex.name


class House(models.Model):
    complex = models.ForeignKey(Complex, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    house_number = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.house_number


class Apartment(models.Model):
    house = models.ForeignKey(House, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    apartment_number = models.IntegerField()
    level = models.IntegerField()
    room = models.IntegerField()
    square = models.FloatField()
    finishing = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price_m = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=1)
    price_total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=1)
    plan_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='complex/apartment/', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.apartment_number
```

Comment: Для дебага просто выведите вверху страницы все получаемые шаблоном переменные. Большинство вопросов после этого отпадают

Answer (score 2):

У вас берется информация о вообще всех квартирах во всех домах всех комплексов. А все потому, что вы забыли отфильтровать запрос к объекту `Apartment`. Судя по всему, view должна выглядеть как-то так:

```py
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['gallery'] = ComplexGallery.objects.filter(complex=context['complex'])
        context['houses'] = House.objects.filter(complex=context['complex'])
        # здесь формируется словарь id_дома: список_квартир
        context['apartments'] = {h.pk: Apartment.objects.filter(house = h) for h in context['houses']}
        return context
```

Comment: А как сделать вывод в шаблоне?